# C function weird syntax

Tags: c

In the Vim source code, the functions are defined like this:

```
    char_u *
crypt_get_key(store, twice)
    int     store;
    int     twice;      /* Ask for the key twice. */
{
   ...
}
```

I am not familiar with this syntax and I don't really understand it. Under which standard it is defined?

Comment: It's K&R C. The standard before C standards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18424897/492405